# Missing JSP support in Jetty, or confusing log message?

Tags: jsp, embedded-jetty

Launching jetty by calling the API in 6.1.24.

The JSP 2.1 component is on the classpath.

```
org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-2.1-jetty:jar:6.1.24:compile
```

But the log says:

```
2010-08-19 08:16:19.443:INFO::NO JSP Support for /basis_ws, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
```

I don't see this message when using the corresponding maven-jetty-plugin.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't do Jetty, so I [looked](http://www.google.com/search?q=jetty+%22no+jsp+support%22+%22did+not+find+org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet%22) a bit round and found [this blog](http://manolocarrasco.blogspot.com/2009/09/tip-enabling-jsp-support-in-jetty700.html). Here's a cite of relevance:

> But, this is not enough, if you start the server you get an error like this:
>
> ```
> INFO::NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
> ```
>
> So you have to enable jsp support in jetty passing additional undocumented options to the jetty start script:
>
> ```
> $ java -jar jetty.jar OPTIONS=Server,jsp
> ```

Comment: Thanks for looking, but the mapping of that to the embedded environment is not obvious. The 'start script' isn't involved at all. However, this is a clue I can follow into the source.

Comment: this is right, it's just thay nowaday one should write something like
--module=server,jmx,resources,websocket,ext,plus,jsp,annotations jsp-impl=apache

instead of OPTIONS - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24524527/jetty-9-module-instead-of-options

Answer (score 21):

I got this problem when I first started with jetty.  The problem is that just including the jsp jars doesn't seem to be enough.  Here's the maven dependency list that I used to solve it.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.2.v20101205</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.2.v20101205</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-jsp-2.1</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.2.v20101205</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-2.1-glassfish</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.v20100127</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: But what if I don't need JSP?

Comment: @Karussell in that case you just dont do anything that is a answer on how to enable JSP support in Jetty? That would sound like a plan to me...

Comment: @JBA you have not understood the problem. I do not need JSP but I still have this confusing log message

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using Jetty 6 under Ubuntu, you may be hitting the problem I described here: https://serverfault.com/a/730626/293452

Briefly, a bug in the Jetty 6.x package dependencies will prevent Jetty from enabling JSP support because of incorrectly linked Tomcat Jasper libraries.