# Jetty 9 "--module" instead of "OPTIONS"

Tags: jetty, cometd, jetty-9

I am trying to switch Jetty from 7.6 to 9.2.

I read and understood that "OPTION" will no more work. So I changed my command from

```
java -jar start.jar --ini **OPTIONS**=server,jmx,resources,websocket,ext,plus,jsp,annotations /u/khandela/project/base//etc/config/cometd/cometd_jetty_config.xml
```

to

```
start.jar --ini **--module**=server,jmx,resources,websocket,ext,plus,jsp,annotations /u/khandela/project/base//etc/config/cometd/cometd_jetty_config.xml
```

But I got below warning:

WARNING: ** Unable to continue, required dependency missing. [jsp-impl/${jsp-impl}-jsp]
WARNING: ** As configured, Jetty is unable to start due to a missing enabled module dependency.
WARNING: ** This may be due to a transitive dependency akin to spdy on npn, which resolves based

How to resolve it ?

Answer (score 2):

The error you are seeing about `[jsp-impl/${jsp-impl}-jsp]` is because a default jsp implementation was not defined when you requested startup of Jetty.

Jetty 9.2.x has [2 different core JSP engines available](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.1.v20140609/jetty-distribution/src/main/resources/modules/jsp.mod).

- `apache` - the Apache Jasper JSP engine (the new Jetty default)
- `glassfish` - the Glassfish Jasper JSP engine (original version in use by Jetty.  Now obsolete / buggy and deprecated)

The behavior in Jetty 9.2 was to force users to decide which implementation they want to use.
This was a mistake and just confuses users that want to start jetty in their own way (ie: not using the `start.ini` or `${jetty.base}` documented mechanisms)

A [feature request was filed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/437395), and the next release of Jetty after 9.2.1 will apply defaults for this value.  With autoselection for `apache`.

In the meantime, while you wait for Jetty 9.2.2 (or 9.3.0), add a property defining which jsp-impl you want to use.

```
$ start.jar --module=server,jmx,resources,websocket,ext,plus,jsp,annotations
     jsp-impl=apache
     /u/khandela/project/base/etc/config/cometd/cometd_jetty_config.xml
```

*Note: get rid of `--ini` as that is not used by start.jar*

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in Netbeans 8.0 to start Jetty 9.2.1. After creating **JettyServer** Jetty started, when I added into actual Jetty Base Locationin to **start.ini**  `jsp-impl=apache` clause.

There is complete listing **start.ini**:

```
#===========================================================
# Jetty start.jar arguments
#
# The contents of this file, together with the *.ini
# files found in start.d directory are used to build
# the classpath and command line on a call to
#    java -jar start.jar [arg...]
#
# Use the following command to see more options
#    java -jar start.jar --help
#
# Each line in these files is prepended to the command line
# as arguments and may be either:
#  + A property like: name=value
#  + A module to enable like: --module=jmx
#  + An XML configuration file like: etc/jetty-feature.xml
#  + A start.jar option like: --dry-run
#
# If --exec or --dry-run are used, then this file may also 
# contain lines with:
#  + A JVM option like: -Xmx2000m 
#  + A System Property like: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
#
# The --add-to-start=module option can be used to append
# a configuration template for a module to start.ini
# The --add-to-startd=module option can be used to create
# a configuration template for a module in start.d/module.ini
# For example configure and run with SPDY use
#
#   java -jar start.jar --add-to-startd=spdy
#   $EDITOR start.d/spdy.ini
#   java -jar start.jar
#   
#===========================================================


#
# Initialize module server
#
#--module=server
--module=server,websocket,jsp,ext,jmx,resources,plus,annotations,commandmanager
# removes bug
jsp-impl=apache
## Server Threading Configuration
# minimum number of threads
threads.min=10
# maximum number of threads
threads.max=200
# thread idle timeout in milliseconds
threads.timeout=60000
# What host to listen on (leave commented to listen on all interfaces)
#jetty.host=myhost.com
# Dump the state of the Jetty server, components, and webapps after startup
jetty.dump.start=false
# Dump the state of the Jetty server, before stop
jetty.dump.stop=false

#
# Initialize module deploy
#
--module=deploy

#
# Initialize module websocket
#
#--module=websocket

#
# Initialize module jsp
#
#--module=jsp
# JSP Configuration
# To use an non-jdk compiler for JSP compilation uncomment next line
# -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true

#
# Initialize module ext
#
#--module=ext

#
# Initialize module resources
#
#--module=resources

#--module=commandmanager
```

By comparing original **start.ini** file, you cas see differences.